# Segue doesn't work because of searchbar

Tags: objective-c, object, search, segue

I have made a table where depending on which cell you click on you will be sent into a new scene (detailviewcontroller). For example if you click on the cell with the text Thailand you will be sent to ThailandDetailViewController (scene). Everything works until you use the searchbar (look under - (void)tableView).

-When some countries get outfiltered (because of the searchfunction) the reaming countries will go higher in the table and acquire a lower count. Which leads to that they will lead to the wrong detailviewcontroller (scene).

A friend of mine said to me that I should use objectAtIndex within my array, didnt really catch what he meant with that.. And make a switch on the cell.textLabel.text (didnt really follow him)

Here is my .m file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.mySearchBar.delegate = self;
self.myTableView.delegate = self;
self.myTableView.dataSource = self;

totalStrings = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"America",@"Austria",@"Canada",@"France",@"Germany",@"Greece",@"Malaysia",@"Mexico",@"Netherlands",@"Poland",@"Russia",@"Singapore",@"Thailand",@"Ukraine", nil];    
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

switch (indexPath.row) {
    case 0: [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Segue0" sender:self];
        break;
    case 1: [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Segue1" sender:self];
        break;
    //and so on
    default: break;
}
}

-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
if(searchText.length == 0){
    isFiltered = NO;
}
else
{
    isFiltered = YES;
    filteredStrings = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (NSString *str in totalStrings){
        NSRange stringRange = [str rangeOfString:searchText      options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        if(stringRange.location !=NSNotFound) {
             [filteredStrings addObject:str];
        }
    }
}
[self.myTableView reloadData];
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath
{
static NSString *Cellidentifier = @"cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:Cellidentifier];

if (!cell) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:Cellidentifier];
}
if (!isFiltered) {
    cell.textLabel.text = [totalStrings objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
else //if it's filtered
{
    cell.textLabel.text = [filteredStrings objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
return cell;
}
```

Big thank you in beforehand!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can have a custom class to store the area and the segue index like this:

```
@interface SegueVO : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *area;
@property int segueIndex;
-(id)initWithArea:(NSString *)area andSegueIndex:(int)index;
@end

@implementation SegueVO
-(id)initWithArea:(NSString *)area andSegueIndex:(int)index
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        self.area = area;
        self.segueIndex = index;
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

You will then store your ares in the totalStrings array like this:

```
[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[[SegueVO alloc] initWithArea:@"America" andIndex:0],....
```

Of course you can create a factory method to cut down on initialisation code.

Now you can work out what segue to activate like this:

```
NSArray *arrayToUse = totalStrings;
if (isFiltered)
   arrayToUse = filteredStrings;

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:[@"Segue" 
 stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", 
 [arrayToUse[indexPath.row].segueIndex]] sender:self];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much, just one quick question is it suppose to say anything else under "Now you can work out what segue to activate like this:"

Comment: No, it's just bad formatting really :) See edited version now, maybe makes more sense this way :)

Answer (score 0):

You could easily solve this problem by storing a custom object in your table's data model instead of an NSString. That object would contain the label to display plus the name of the segue to activate once selected.

It's another question why you'd want a totally different view controller for different data. I suppose these are different kinds of data that need different ways to deal with them.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: OK I'll give another answer as it is not easy to put code decently in comments.